# Read mail Attachment files in Android2.1?

Tags: android

I configure email by using the android2.1 emulator. When I download the files from mail attachment I get the path **content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/1/RAW**

I need to read that file data. How to read the data from the device.??
Is there any permission to read file from the phone memory.
My code is here:

```
 intent = getIntent();        
 String str_sel_fname=intent.getDataString();
```

In the eclipse file explorer /data/data/com.android.email/databases/1.db_att/**1**

here 1 is store the attachment file .Now can anyone help me to get the data from that.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `getContentResolver().openInputStream()`. [`openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) should give you an `InputStream` on that content `Uri`.

Comment: Thanks for your Response I got it